# Plesk using outdated password for MYSQL5.7

Tags: windows, mysql, plesk, mysql5

I'm unable to login to my Plesk control panel, or even pull up the page.

Plesk's repair utilities fail to work, so web/GUI methods seem to be entirely unavailable.

The only way I can login is via command:

```
mysql -u admin -p [entering correct password]
```

But Plesk itself cannot connect to MYSQL 5.7, because it's using whatever the old password was.

How do I update the password that Plesk uses to connect to MySQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Pointers for updating the Plesk MySQL password

1. According to the ["The Plesk shows the error: Cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+ using the old insecure authentication"](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213957065-The-Plesk-shows-the-error-Cannot-connect-to-MySQL-4-1-using-the-old-insecure-authentication) post, you can go to `Plesk` > `Domains` > `example.com` > `Databases` > `User Management` > `database_name` and in the the new window submit the new password.
2. Additionally, according to the ["Plesk is not accessible: Access denied for user 'username' @'localhost' (using password YES)"](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004222334-Plesk-is-not-accessible-Access-denied-for-user-username-localhost-using-password-YES-) post, you can run `plesk sbin psadb -u --password="password"` with the new password from command line.

---

### Additional Resources & References

- [Updating MySQL Pre-4.1 Password Hashes to be MySQL 5.6 Compatible](https://www.hostdime.com/kb/display/HR/Updating+MySQL+Pre-4.1+Password+Hashes+to+be+MySQL+5.6+Compatible)
- [The Plesk shows the error: Cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+ using the old insecure authentication](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213957065-The-Plesk-shows-the-error-Cannot-connect-to-MySQL-4-1-using-the-old-insecure-authentication)
- [Plesk is not accessible: Access denied for user 'username' @'localhost' (using password YES)](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004222334-Plesk-is-not-accessible-Access-denied-for-user-username-localhost-using-password-YES-)

Comment: I have some feedback in my own answer, but thanks for giving me the route to the right track. Your first option though was unavailable to me because I couldn't access the plesk website to begin with.

Comment: @user10902472 I'm glad I could help and that you were able to get it resolved. Thanks for sharing the updated and explicit detail from your answer too. This may save others a headache or two in the future which we helped contribute to.

Answer (score 3):

Following the instructions on a link shared by [Pimp Juice's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1393330/984065), Typing `plesk db` gave me the error: `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

The solution was to combine the two, as I can't find a documented way that plesk db allows username and password options

1. Run mysql: `mysql -u admin -p MyMySQLAdminPassword`, which is what `plesk db` was trying to do with the credentials it knows.
2. Paste the command `UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD("MyMySQLAdminPassword") WHERE user='admin';`
3. `quit` MYSQL
4. Run the command: `plesk sbin psadb -u --password="MyMySQLAdminPassword"`, quotes included.